# Company VPN on personal PC

Tags: vpn

So the people at my new work set up a vpn on my personal pc today, windows style, so now when I go into network tab I can pick their company connection. What they don't know is that I have another client where I use citrix. Will connecting to the company vpn system wide let them know I have another client? Basically, can they know what I do on my personal PC, regardless whether it's another work or porn as long as I'm connected to their vpn? Am I forced to run it in a VM?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but installing a corporate VPN on a personnal PC is an assurance for security nightmares. The organization may not disallow anything on a personnal PC, so anything can be installed there. But through the VPN, that machine will be able to access the corporate network... Furthermore, the user could misuse the VPN and use it including for private usages, which gives the admins a visibility on private things that they should not know. Only my opinion, but I think that it should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, can they know what I do on my personal PC, regardless whether it's another work or porn as long as I'm connected to their vpn?

The simplified answer is yes. They can. While they can certainly configure it in a way they don't get to know what you are doing, or they could simply not care to ever look into their logs, chances are they will.

You should not do anything but work related things while you are connected to your work VPN.

If you have another job, you can disconnect from the company VPN and *then* work your other job. If you want to do private surfing, disconnect from the company VPN and *then* do what you want to do. They cannot find out anything while you are not connected to them.

If you want to be 100% safe from both software and human errors, buy second PC where you never configure your work VPN that you can use to do other things on. On the cheaper side, you can probably find software or configuration that tunnels only your work software through your work VPN.

But yes, anything that goes through the work VPN can potentially be noticed and read by your work's IT department. Even if it's super encrypted and they cannot figure out what *excatly* you did, they will know you had a connection to some-competitor.com open for a long time.